# TeX Live Manager crashes with "Unknown docfile tag"

Tags: errors, texlive, updating

Today my TeX Live 2013 stopped updating packages. I use `tlmgr` to update packages but it's crashing with the following error:

```
$ sudo tlmgr update
Unknown docfile tag:  texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf details=""Quick start" documentation" at /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 127, <TMP> line 127939.
```

The command

```
 sudo tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed
```

does not fix it.

Comment: For some reasons, the double quotes surrounding `Quick Start` are not escaped. There is already a [fix by Norbert](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm?sortby=file&r1=31656&r2=31655&pathrev=31656), I guess we all just need to know how to fix our own distribution. For the moment I solved it myself by editing `/usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb` and removing (or escaping with ``\"``) those quotes (see http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-September/034150.html)

Comment: Thanks ChrisS for you help. In my case replacing the TLPOBJ.pm file with the trunk version solved the problem.

Comment: @egreg: Please convert that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 24):

For some reasons (a bug in the Perl script, it appears), the double quotes surrounding `Quick Start` in the docfile tag are not properly escaped.

A fix has already been uploaded in the TeX Live repository, (see [here](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm?sortby=file&r1=31656&r2=31655&pathrev=31656) for the differences or [here](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm?view=log&sortby=file&pathrev=31656) for downloading the new version of the Perl module).

The easiest fix, before the new version of `tlmgr` propagates, is to remove the offending quotes from the file located at

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
```

so the line becomes

```
texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf details="Quick start documentation"
```

The error message one gets shows the line number, which can vary depending on many factors: in your case it's at line 127939, on my system it was different (128963). On standard TeX Live installations, editing the file requires superuser privileges.

***UPDATE***

As of September 18, 2013, it seems that all traces of the bad quotes have disappeared from the catalogues. So, whoever didn't update TeX Live in the past few days should experience no problems and updating TeX Live should happen without any problem.

Here's how to proceed in case an update in the last few days has triggered the "misplced quote" bug.

#### MacTeX

MacTeX users experimenting the problem should, when experiencing problems,

1. Launch TeX Live Utility and reinstall `tlmgr`: menu “Actions > Reinstall TeX Live Manager”
2. Relaunch TeX Live Utility
3. Perform the infrastructure update
4. Update all TeX Live packages

Prior to the full update it may not be possible to access at the package list tab, because a wrong `pythontex` entry hangs the Python script used by TeX Live Utility.

#### GNU/Linux systems

Users running a vanilla TeX Live on their GNU/Linux systems should

1. Download `http://mirror/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh` either with `wget` or `curl -O`
2. Acquire super user privileges and run `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh` making sure that the TeX Live binaries directory is first in the `root` user's `PATH` variable; for example (assuming a Bash shell)

   ```
   sudo su
   export PATH=/opt/texbin:${PATH}
   sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh
   tlmgr update --self
   tlmgr update --all
   exit
   ```

   The `/opt/texbin` should be replaced by the actual path to the TeX Live binaries or by a symbolic link pointing to it (on my GNU/Linux systems I always define a symbolic link `/opt/texbin`).

Comment: Hi I discovered the same issue.

However i do not see the line

texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf details="Quick start documentation"
in my texlive.tlpdb

Are there any suggestions how to solved this

Comment: @wierts Reinstall `tlmgr`; how to do it depends on your system. With TeX Live Utility there's a menu entry for it.

Comment: Editing this line quite simply does not fix the problem. Even grepping the directory per nitrous's suggestion and changing them all does not fix the problem. The suggestion to reinstall tlmgr does not work, because  tlmgr will not update or reinstall itself because of the error.

Comment: @frabjous On one machine I had the error, even if `pythontex` was not installed; I asked TeX Live Utility to reinstall `tlmgr` and it happened without a glitch.

Comment: Using the `TLPOBJ.pm` was the best solution for me.

Comment: @egreg i did come across the issue the last days. As you suggested i updated my tlmgr.
In the log of tex live i get the following messages:
 `2013-09-18 12:01:10 +0000 Notice -[TLMLoadDatabaseOperation _dumpDatabaseAtURL:asPropertyList:][2667] Caught exception in reading stderr for dump task: *** -[NSConcreteFileHandle availableData]: Resource temporarily unavailable`

also it gave a Parse Error (this too long to copy here) 

do you have any suggestions (other then reinstall Mactex)?

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution for Mac OS X:

```
cd /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/
mv TLPOBJ.pm TLPOBJ-31644.pm
curl http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm?view=co -o TLPOBJ.pm
```

Then you can run:

```
sudo tlmgr update
```

Note that it would be better to delete unnecessary backup file:

```
rm /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ-31644.pm
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be several files which contain this error, if you still get this after trying egreg's solution, you can try searching `/usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/tlpobj/pythontex.tlpobj` for `""Quick start" documentation"` and removing the extraneous quotes.

If you still get the error, you could try running `grep -nr '"Quick start"' /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg`. This should list any more files with the offending quotes in. Note that some files listed by this command may be backups of earlier files, but it probably doesn't matter too much if you change those as well.

### How to use `vim` to correct the error

If you are unsure of how to edit the files, try:

`sudo vim /path/to/file`

Then type the line number, followed by G (such as `127939G` in OP's case; the `grep` tool should tell you the line numbers of any extra copies if needed). Next, type `i`, then use the arrow keys to navigate to the offending quotes and delete them with backspace. Finally, press the escape key, type `:x`, and press enter.

### If nothing works (last resort)

***Firstly**, you should try to wait for the new tlmgr update to filter through in case that provides a simple fix in the next few days.*

Otherwise, to manually uninstall TeXLive, try the following (make sure this is how it is installed in your machine):

```
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/texlive/2013
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

This should allow you to reinstall again. Watch out though, when you reinstall TeXLive (depending on the version you downloaded) you may install the `""Quick start" documentation"` bug again!

**N.B.** My tips assume you are running this on a *nix system (UNIX, Linux, OS X, etc).

Comment: Did this. Changed three files. Still didn't work.

Comment: @frabjous Sorry to hear that. I think you have two options, either wait for the new update to come (which hopefully will install fine for you), or you can try manually uninstalling TeX Live. I'll update my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: @frabjous -- the answer given by Takeshi Nagae worked for me, without having to uninstall and reinstall vast parts of the TeXLive distribution. :-)

Comment: I seemed to get the problem reoccur today unfortunately, but I tried that answer and it also seemed to work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should do the trick (this assumes a global installation into /usr/local/, so modify the destination to suit your installation, and skip the `sudo` if it's a single-user install)

```
sudo wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm -O /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm
```

This is the what seeberg suggested in the comments, but this should more or less dummy-proof it.